# 403 error response from IIS on almost alternate request while load testing api

Tags: performance, iis, deployment, asp.net-core-webapi, load-testing

I have a web api which is deployed on IIS.
Api's are going through load test using load runner and almost on all alternative api call, getting 403 error response code, struggling to identify the issue, call is not going to the API, its returned back from IIS

Comment: 403 error indicates that access to the requested URL by the client is Forbidden for some reason. you need to provide detailed error message snapshot and what is the sub status code. and check that you assign this permission to the site folder:1) IIS_IUSRS,2)NETWORK SERVICE,3)IUSR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing bearer token authorization, somehow token which were incoming with each request were not valid, that is why the issue was occurring, to overcome this we have increased the lifetime of token to 1 hour and request load test team to generate the token once and send that token only with each request so that we can now see the proper execution time for each end point.

Answer (score 0):

403 error indicates that access to the requested URL by the client is Forbidden for some reason. you need to provide detailed error message snapshot and what is the sub status code. and check that you assign this permission to the site folder:1) IIS_IUSRS,2)NETWORK SERVICE,3)IUSR